# formating of databricks notebook titles like header,point

Tags: databricks

How to make the notebook cmd title has format like in the picture ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use markdown for this:

```
%md
###The next command...

1. Select color...
2. Displays a table...
```

See also the [Databricks documentation.](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/user-guide/notebooks/notebook-use.html#include-documentation)